# Al mover imagen se me corre toda la matriz

Tags: c#

estoy armando un ajedrez en winform c#, bien, el problema que tengo es el siguiente, estoy haciendo una pieza, ahora digamos estoy haciendo su movimiento, el tema es que el tablero que arme, se me corre al mover la pieza, tienen idea que puede ser?

Aquí les dejo el código

Esto seria el tablero:

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics cuadrado = e.Graphics;
        SolidBrush BN = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));

        SolidBrush BB = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)); 


        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {

                A = A + 52;

                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cuadrado.FillRectangle(BB, 10 + A, 10 + B, 50, 50);

                }
                else
                {
                    cuadrado.FillRectangle(BN, 10 + A, 10 + B, 50, 50);


                }




            }
            A = 0;
            B = B + 52;

        }


    }
```

Esto seria la pieza:

```
        public void pieza(object sender, PaintEventArgs a) { 

        Graphics g = a.Graphics;
        SolidBrush C = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        Rectangle R;

        g.FillRectangle(C, 400 + _X , 400 + _Y, 10, 10);


    }
```

Con este codigo muevo la pieza:

```
        private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.W))
        {

            _Y -= 20;
            _X += 20;
            Refresh();
        }

        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.S))
        {

            _Y += 20;
            _X -= 20;
            Refresh();
        }

    }
```

Las variables _Y, _X son publicas globales, a propósito, para poder permitir mover la pieza ... Pero como les digo, al mover la pieza, automáticamente se me mueve toda la matriz, digamos que tiene dos variables global, que son A y B, pero en ningún momento les doy algún tipo de efecto para que tengan cambio en su valor, mas que el que se efectúa dentro del for. Yo lo que necesitaría es que el tablero, permanezca quieto y no se mueva bajo ningún tipo de circunstancia.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he resuelto, por si quieren, les dejo la solucion, era una cosa muy simple.

```
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics cuadrado = e.Graphics;
    SolidBrush BN = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0));

    SolidBrush BB = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)); 


    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {

            A = A + 52;

            if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
            {
                cuadrado.FillRectangle(BB, 10 + A, 10 + B, 50, 50);

            }
            else
            {
                cuadrado.FillRectangle(BN, 10 + A, 10 + B, 50, 50);


            }




        }
        A = 0;
        B = B + 52;

    }

 //Aqui iba esto

B = 0;

}
```

De esta manera logro que la matriz no se corra, sucede que cada vez que llamaba a la funcion "refresh()" ... Refrescaba la variable B ya acumulada, entonces la matriz de dibujo se iba para cualquier lado y no se fijaba como deberia.

```
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(819, 444);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pieza);
        this.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.Form1_KeyPress);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

Estuve observando, que aqui para superponer las imagenes, van en orden, de quien va tomar la superposicion, bueno, no se si "existe" alguna manera de predefinirlo, pero por el momento lo voy regulando asi